# Use Create-React-App with antd

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I tried to use [antd](https://ant.design/) with [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

I installed antd in project using

```
yarn add antd
```

Added a button using antd's button component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Still, button did not rendering correctly. When inspecting the element, I find that antd classes are being applied. It's just that css is not loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add antd/dist/antd.css at the top of src/App.css.

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I figured out this from [antd's official docs for using with Create React  App](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app)

So all the steps required are to install antd

```
yarn add antd
```

Use a component from antd

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And import antdcss in main css file (src/App.css)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Although verified answer works, **you could minimize the size of the CSS bundle in the build** by only importing required CSS as follows.</s>

```
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
import 'antd/lib/button/style/css'; // importing only the required CSS
```

**Update**

Recently noticed even importing antd components according to above mentioned way(strike through text) it still adds unnecessary JS in to the build,

I even tried  react-app-rewired in [ant design docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app) issue still the same ( still adds unnecessary JS in to the build ). So I opened an issue on the antd repo : https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/13274

**Update 2:**

Please take a look at : https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12011

Comment: This will still import a lot of unnecessary styles since `'antd/lib/button/style/css'` import the base css.

Comment: @KevinHe Do you have better solution? If so go on an edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After installing antd in your project you can import button as

import {Button} from 'antd';

Answer (score 0):

First install less-loader on npm via `npm i less-loader`,
then create a index.less folder on the index.js directory.
paste this on index.less -> `@import "~antd/dist/antd.dark.less";`
After that import this .less file to your index.js and have fun :)
You can find some other methods [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app)

You can also use craco(create react app config override) but its more complicated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).